# How to serialize a class into a file on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, serialization

I'm having some trouble with an updated version of my app on the App Store.

I have a database with a person's info. However, if the user has the version 1.0 and updates to 2.0, I need to save this database.

I want to serialize it into a file on the iPhone so that when version 2.0 is being installed, it will completely remove version 1.0 and then deserialize the database Class back into the app.

How can I serialize/deserialize a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data's simple then look into [archives and serialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i).

If the data's complex, where you really need database function, then you can use [sqlite](http://www.scribd.com/doc/11524402/iPhone-Programming-with-SQLite).

Comment: Thanks, I've found the answer. Used a .plist to store my info and get it from there anytime I need it.

Answer (score 4):

If your class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, you can use [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to serialize it, and then the [NSKeyedUnarchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to deserialize it. Both classes support using data objects or a file on disk.

Comment: You should read Apple's ["Archives and Serializations Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) in order to understand your serialization options and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the data is stored in an NSDictionary or an NSArray, you can have it write a plist out with "writeToFile:atomically:"

Comment: This will only work if all items in the collection can be serialized as plist items. If you have custom classes, you won't be able to use this method.